# Database Error : Compiling app on iphone device

Tags: iphone

I am getting a problem when i compile my iphone database application to device.
When i debug the code it says database path "out of scope" on the break point and it does not compile the statement. Below is the code i am using to access the database.

```
databaseName = @"Zen.sqlite";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
```

It works perfectly fine when i use the same code on simulator. Please help me to get this work on iphone device as well.
Thanks.

Comment: The problem probably lies somewhere else. Show us more code!
Also, see: #749504.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually problems while testing sqlite on iPhone. The simple answer:

1. Remove your app from the iPhone
2. Clean all targets in Xcode
3. Build and install again

Comment: it works fine when i run on simulator. And when i open the sqlite file from Applications folder of simulator it shows me all the tables and data.

the problem arises when i run app on device. I downloaded the application from device and i checked the sqlite database files there were no tables in it.

please help me solving this problem. thanks.

Comment: Have you removed your app from the phone? And then installed it again?